# How do I order my data based on the names of my list?

Tags: r

My list looks something like this:
[image]

I have converted the string values (such as rs267) to numbers but when I try:

```
lapply(list, function(x) sort(x))
```

My data ends up being sorted by the values of the list. But I want it to be sorted by the name values, since these are numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the `names` (`character`) to `numeric`, apply `order` and use that index for ordering the `list`

```
list[order(as.numeric(names(list)))]
```

Comment: How comes you can apply order inside [] rather than as a method?

Comment: @github292929 probably you are mixing syntax from other language with R